# Unable to get Spring to populate a select box with options

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I've tried several different options but I cannot seem to be able to populate a dropdown list unless I use static html data which i'm trying to avoid.

My simple case is:

Generate ModelAndView to be rendered, use value from object as the list of options and tadaaa.

Simple controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView indexPage(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws Exception {

    ArrayList<String> numberOfKids = new ArrayList<String>();
    numberOfKids.add("-Small People-");
    numberOfKids.add("0");
    numberOfKids.add("1");
    numberOfKids.add("2");

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
    modelAndView.addObject("numberOfKids", numberOfKids);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

View:  I've tried both the Spring variant of having form:select and form:options and the thyme leaf version - neither of which are rendering.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form:select name="numberOfKids" id="numberOfKids" tabindex="3">
        <option th:each="number : ${numberOfKids}"
            th:value="${number}"
            th:text="${number}">
        </option>
     </form:select>
</div>
```

in the console, there are no values and it also has a class of display: none which is odd as I haven't added it.

Any hero appreciated, I imagine its something small as I'm rushing about but can't bring the focus back in - and my debugger has died a slow painful death which isn't helping. :(

Edit:
Weirder still...
If I copy that block into another select, the second one populates...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="numberOfAdults" id="numberOfAdults" tabindex="2">
        <option th:each="String : ${numberOfKids}" th:value="${String}" th:text="${String}">
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <form:select name="numberOfKids" id="numberOfKids" tabindex="3">
        <option th:each="String : ${numberOfKids}" th:value="${String}" th:text="${String}">
        </option>
    </form:select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use JSP tags as `<form:select/>` in Thymeleaf templates, because Thymeleaf can't process this tags. Instead use just simple html `<select/>` tag:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="numberOfKids" id="numberOfKids" tabindex="3">
        <option th:each="String : ${numberOfKids}" th:value="${String}" th:text="${String}">
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`thymeleaf` doesn't understand `<form:select... />` (This tag is JSP taglib). Instead you should use `<select th:field="*{numberOfKids}">`. For more info [read this](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#dropdownlist-selectors).

Comment: You right, except that `th:field` not needed in this case. Because there is not `path` attribute in <form:select> tag of original code. Anyway, vote up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form:select items="${numberOfKids}" />
```

Usually it's used with a Map instead of List, so you will have the text and value filled in.

Comment: I had tried that before but it also didn't work. I'm now starting to wonder if it's anything to do with the jQuery plugin select box.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the whole thing. Usually when using spring forms you must declare a path attribute, which is the object that will receive the values when the form is posted.